# Generating every outcome possible when parsing a list : element(N, L,X)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement a simple element(N,L,X) predicate, where L is a list, X an element of the list, and N the position of this element in the list.
I want to be able to do that :

```
element(3, [a,b,c,d,e], X). 
yes : X=c.

element(N, [a,b,c,d,e], X).  
yes : { N=1, X=a}; { N=2, X=b}; ... { N=5, X=e};
```

I am sure I have seen this somewhere, but I can't find it.
Thanks.

Comment: Try `nth1(N, [a,b,c,d,e], X).`

Comment: Don't have the right to use it since its part of my course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to describe a relation between a *list*, a potential *element* of that list and its *position*, why not give the predicate a more descriptive name, e.g. list_element_position/3. Then consider what the relation should describe. Basically there are two cases:

1) The head of the list matches the element. In that case you already know a position for that element. But there might be other occurrences as well, so:

2) Regardless whether the head matches the element or not, we should take a look at the tail of the list as well, since there might be further occurrences.

An accumlator can be used to count the positions. I take it from your first example that you'd like to start counting at `1`. Putting all that together you could write something like:

```
list_element_position(L,E,P) :-
   list_element_position_(L,E,P,1).         % start counting at 1

list_element_position_([X|Xs],X,P,P).       % case 1)
list_element_position_([X|Xs],Y,R,P0) :-    % case 2)
   P1 is P0+1,
   list_element_position_(Xs,Y,R,P1).
```

Your example queries:

```
   ?- list_element_position([a,b,c,d,e],E,3).
E = c ? ;
no
   ?- list_element_position([a,b,c,d,e],E,X).
E = a,
X = 1 ? ;
E = b,
X = 2 ? ;
E = c,
X = 3 ? ;
E = d,
X = 4 ? ;
E = e,
X = 5 ? ;
no
```

Multiple occurrences of an element:

```
   ?- list_element_position([a,b,c,d,e,a],a,X).
X = 1 ? ;
X = 6 ? ;
no
```

If you only intend to use the predicate with the first argument being ground, this already works fine. However, if you want to ask questions like: What lists are there with a certain element, say `a`, at a certain position, say `1`?:

```
   ?- list_element_position(L,a,1).
L = [a|_A] ? ;
```

You get one answer and then the predicate loops. You can avoid that by adding a goal with length/2 to list_element_position/3:

```
list_element_position(L,E,P) :-
   length(L,_),                       % <- here
   list_element_position_(L,E,P,1).
```

The above query now produces additional solutions:

```
   ?- list_element_position(L,a,1).
L = [a] ? ;
L = [a,_A] ? ;
L = [a,_A,_B] ? ;
L = [a,_A,_B,_C] ? ;
...
```

Or even better, you can avoid the loop by using clpfd and adding a goal in list_element_position_/4 to ensure that the accumlator does not become larger than the actual position:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_element_position(L,E,P) :-
   list_element_position_(L,E,P,1).

list_element_position_([X|Xs],X,P,P).
list_element_position_([X|Xs],Y,R,P0) :-
   R #> P0,                                  % <- here
   P1 #= P0+1,
   list_element_position_(Xs,Y,R,P1).
```

This way the query yields a single solution and terminates subsequently:

```
   ?- list_element_position(L,a,1).
L = [a|_A] ? ;
no
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, sir !

Comment: @Chuck: You're welcome. I just updated my answer to include another possible usage of the predicate.

Comment: Why not avoid the looping?

Comment: @false: That's actually a very good point. I updated my answer, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @tas Thanks for the details. Really appreciate it.